# Virtualbox (Windows10): Document is empty

Tags: virtualbox

Using VirtualBox I occurred this error:

```
Document is empty

Location: 'C:\Users\a\VirtualBox VMs\ubuntu\ubuntu.vbox', line 1(0), column 1

E_FAIL (0x80004005)
```

I searched for this situation and found out most people solved it by rename `VirtualBox.xml-prev` as `VirtualBox.xml`. However, this didn't work out for me.

Any other solutions?

Comment: Solution: cd to dir with ubuntu.vbox, see if ubuntu.vbox-prev is there. If yes, remove ubuntu.vbox and rename ubuntu.vbox-prev to ubuntu.vbox